# Which is the country whose government has the largest public ownership in the world (net worth) over most of its natural resources?

Tags: economy, government, international

> Venezuela is another contemporary example that we have of the
> detrimental effects of socialism on the environment. At one point a
> couple of decades ago, Venezuela was the wealthiest nation in Latin
> America. Then it took a turn for the worst as it decided to go the
> socialist route. And where did that route take them?
>
> Venezuela is a very rich country when it comes to its abundance of
> natural resources. Today, much of those natural resources are
> government-owned. This means that there are no owners practicing
> private property rights over those resources, the kind of ownership
> which motivates them to manage their resources well.

https://caseforconservatism.com/environment/socialisms-historical-destruction-of-the-environment/

Which government owns the most amount of natural resource (net worth)? I heard that China doesn't allow private ownership of its country's natural resources, but I couldn't find a single source on the Internet that confirm this. So I was wondering if this was true and also which country has the largest public ownership (in the world) over most of its natural resources? In Canada and the U.S. most natural resources are owned by private companies, so I was wondering how countries compared in terms of government ownership of the resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frame challenge: It is not the only important variable.

On the planet Earth, it is likely that Russia owns the most natural resources. The reason being is that Russia has huge territory and it is very likely that it is full of untapped, yet undiscovered natural resources. That land is mostly unowned by any private entity or sometimes owned but without the clearance to resource extraction.

The *limitation* being, most of these resources are undiscovered, and the ones that are discovered are very expensive to extract (and discover before that), often making that extraction uneconomical. The issue of Venezuela is that it's not that hard to extract oil in tropical setting. So it is possible to have massive profits and pocket those without giving much to the community. Whereas in Russia, most of mining activities involve building cities in the middle of tundra, a significant amount of labor is needed which has to be paid for, with these money getting into the local economy.

Henceforth, Venezuela is a country analog of someone getting fat on fast carbs, whereas Russia being on whole grain diet.

Now, most of the resources in existence are not oil. Lithium deposits, Rare Earths and Bauxite are all resources and cost money, but their development barely breaks even. That's your fats and proteins and sometimes vitamins.